# Entity Framework Query with two sub levels

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a SQL question that i need to ask the experts.   To be honest i dont even know how to ask it so i will do so by example.

I have my top level table called Clients
My Clients have Locations so i have a table called Locations
Each location has Contacts so i have a table called Contacts

Relationship in SQL looks like

Clients --->  Locations ---> Contacts.

Notice there is no direct relationship defined between Clients and Contacts.

I need to return all clients for a give Client.

How can i do this using Entity Frame work?

Comment: Did you mean all contacts for a given client? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a LINQ to Entities query:

```
context.Clients.SelectMany(
    client => client.Locations.Select(
        location => location.Contacts)).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: I assumed that you meant contacts for a given client and that your question is a LINQ to Entities and not SQL question. (Since you specified EF.)